# C macro for removing all input code except protected parts

Tags: c, preprocessor

Given that C comments are processed before preprocessor macros, and that it seems it's not possible to insert comments from macros, I'm wondering if what I have in my mind would be impossible to achieve with the C preprocessor. Imagine this piece of code:

```
KEEP_SPECIFIED_TEXT_ONLY( int myfunc(const char *strarg) {
   char str1[] = "just a test";
   KEEP(char) str2[] = "voila";
   int a=2;
   double b=1.0;

   if(!strcmp(strarg,str1)) return 1;
   if(!strcmp(KEEP(strarg),str2)) return 2;
   return 0;
}
)
```

And then I want to process that part twice. In one of the invocations, both the `KEEP_SPECIFIED_TEXT_ONLY` macro and the `KEEP` macro will be defined as `#define M(X) X`, thus the output will be compilable code.

But in the second invocation, I wish to get just `char strarg` as output, removing all the rest of code that was typed outside of `KEEP()`.

Actually, I don't need to really remove the unprotected input, because it's meant to be compiled, as in the first invocation. So, if there was some way of making the compiler ignore text without it being removed nor without using comments, it would work too.

Is that possible, or do I need to use [m4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(computer_language)) for something like this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to get at the second invocation. you've written " I wish to get just char strarg as output, removing all the rest of code that was typed outside of KEEP()." can you give the result code you want to get at the second invocation?

Comment: This sounds like XY problem. What is the real problem you are trying to solve with this?